# Заменить одинаковые значение в атрибутах на новые

Tags: javascript, jquery

Прошу вашей помощи, я не селен в JavaScript. При создание нового элемента, я клонирую предыдущий и вношу в него изменения, а именно новые данные созданного элемента.

Задача состоит в том чтобы при клонирование заменить одинаковые данные старого элемента на новый.

Клонирую это:

```
<tr id="68" class="row_id_68 prices">
    <td>1</td>
    <td class="name">СПб</td>
    <td>
        <a class="list_button open" data-method="post" title="Открыть" rel="68|prices|routes"></a>
    </td>
    <td>
        <a class="list_button del" title="Удалить маршрут 'СПб'?" id="68" rel="prices"></a>
    </td>    
</tr>
```

И во всех атрибутах, где есть цифра 68, надо заменить на новую, например 69.

Функция клонирования:

```
var old_id = $("body").find('.table tr').first().attr("id");

$("body").find('.row_id_'+old_id).first().clone().prependTo('.table')
```

Comment: а где функция, которой клонируете? Или вы просто `cloneNode`?

Comment: `$("body").find('.add_'+data['table']+' .row_id_'+old_id).first().clone().prependTo('.add_'+data['table'])`

Comment: в вопрос добавьте)

Comment: извините, готово ))

Comment: А если 69 уже существует? Сперва нужно посчитать общее количество `let i = document.querySelectorAll('tr.prices').length;` а при клонировании, менять все числа на `i = i + 1`. P.s. у вас все элементы железобетонно будут с такой разметкой или произвольно могут меняться? Если такой, то легче будет заранее зная все места - отыскать их и поменять число...

Comment: Нет, 69 не существует. Я создаю новый материал, добавляю его в БД, и из БД получаю новый id, и заменяю им клонируемый элемент. И не факт что это будет 69, это может быть и 129.

Comment: Раз вы создаете новый, так и создавайте новые элементы, не надо клонировать существующие. Создаете новый, устанавливаете нужные атрибуты, добавляете в таблицу.

Comment: @Stepan, Дело в том что я делаю универсальную функцию для разных страниц сайта, и в tr может быть вложено разное количество td, очень много переменных, но я знаю только то, что остается неизменным только цифра.

Answer (score 0):

Еще раз повторю, я только изучаю JavaScript, но кроме как пройти циклом, ничего придумать не смог. Может есть решение проще это все сделать?.

```
$(function(){
var data = {'table' : 'prices',
            'id' : '69',
            'name': 'новый'
        };


var old_id = $("body").find('.add_'+data['table']+' tr').first().attr("id");
var old_name = $("body").find('.add_'+data['table']+' tr .name').first().html();


var new_tr = $("body").find('.add_'+data['table']+' .row_id_'+old_id).first().clone()
.prependTo('.add_'+data['table']).attr('id', data['id']);

$('tr#'+new_tr.attr("id")+' *').each(function (index, element) {
  if($(element).attr("id")){
    $(this).attr("id", data['id'])
  }
  if($(element).attr("rel")){
    $(this).attr('rel', $(this).attr("rel").replace(old_id, data['id']))     
  }
  if($(element).attr("class")){
    $(this).attr('class', $(this).attr("class").replace(old_id, data['id']))     
  }
  if($(element).attr("title")){
    $(this).attr('title', $(this).attr("title").replace(old_name, data['name']))     
  }
  if($(element).html() == old_name){
    $(this).html(data['name'])     
  }
 });
});
```